# How to make a sidebar menu

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I'm looking for a way to develop a menu which could be visible by sliding on the left of the current screen. One example is the mobile version of Firefox, when you slide on the left, you can access to the current tabs navigation, but the main page is still visible. It is called a sidebar I think :

[EXAMPLE](http://blog.higosoft.com/wp-content/uploads/auto_save_image/2012/01/093122XSx.png)

One possible way to do that is to use ViewFlipper, I guess, but maybe is there an easier and more efficient possibility ? And I'm afraid that handling scrolling horizontally and vertically could be a bit difficult...

Thanks for any answers,

Maxetx.

Comment: use slider drawer, its easy to use and have all that you need try this link https://mobibear.wordpress.com/2010/07/12/android-slidingdrawer-with-custom-view/ and this link too. http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/12/01/slidingdrawer-in-android-a-simple-example/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe this will give you an idea

https://github.com/korovyansk/android-fb-like-slideout-navigation

https://github.com/walkingice/gui-sliding-sidebar

Comment: Thanks, I think your answer, blessenm, will be better than mak's for what I need to do, despite that I don't really like using external libraries in my projects :s

Answer (score 3):

You may try out [SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu). There is example in lib.